# Permanently hide the Task List window in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, testing, build, biztalk

I haven't been able to find an answer for this online, but basically I want to permanently hide the Task List window that pops up whenever I test a Biztalk map. Right now I've found a temp solution by minimizing the window as much as possible, so it doesnt get in the way, but it would be nice to get rid of it entirely.

[image]

This is the window in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (for clarity, the answer is no...unless you want to write an Shell Extension ;).

I'm often as frustrated by this as you but have found that simply tucking it away in a corner or along the status bar is just as good as hiding it.

I presume the activate action is baked into the map designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following extension for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to automatically close the Task List window once it is displayed:

```
public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        events = DTE.Events;
        windowEvents = events.WindowEvents;
        windowEvents.WindowActivated += OnWindowActivated;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        windowEvents.WindowActivated -= OnWindowActivated;
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(EnvDTE.Window gotFocus, EnvDTE.Window lostFocus)
    {
        try
        {
            if (gotFocus.Caption == "Task List")
                CloseWindow(gotFocus);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private void CloseWindow(EnvDTE.Window w)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new System.Action(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 w.Close();
             }
             catch (System.Exception)
             {
             }
         }
                ));
    }

    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.WindowEvents windowEvents;
}
```